# How to update an Account field value from an External Service after a future call

Tags: json, httpresponse

I am integrating Salesforce with an external ERP system.

The create/update of accounts in SF, requires that I update/create them in the external system, and also keep the External's ID, within my Account Object - for future usage.

It starts with an after update trigger on the account

```
trigger trgSF2NSAccount on Account (after update) {

    String jsonData;

    // Create a list of integers to write to the JSON string.
    List<Id> idlist = new List<Id>();


    for(Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        JSONGenerator jsGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        jsGen.writeStartObject();

        jsGen.writeStringField('mappingtype', 'Account_Customer_Mapping');
        jsGen.writeStringField('recordtype', 'Account');
        jsGen.writeStringField('Name', acc.name);
        jsGen.writeStringField('CurrencyIsoCode', acc.CurrencyIsoCode);
        idlist.add(acc.Id);
        jsGen.writeStringField('Id', acc.Id);
// SOBJECT USER        jsGen.writeStringField('Owner', acc.Owner);
        jsGen.writeStringField('Customer_Status__c', 'Closed_Won');

        if(acc.Website != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Website', 'http://' + acc.Website);
        if(acc.Fax != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Fax', acc.Fax);

// SOBJECT ACCount        jsGen.writeStringField('Parent', acc.Parent);
        if (acc.Phone != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Phone', acc.Phone);
        if (acc.Phone_2__c != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Phone_2__c', acc.Phone_2__c);


        // Handle Shipping and Billing Address
        jsGen.writeFieldName('ShippingAddress');
        jsGen.writeStartArray();

        // Create Billing address
        jsGen.writeStartObject();
        jsGen.writeStringField('Country', acc.BillingCountryCode);
        if (acc.BillingCity != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('City', acc.BillingCity );
        jsGen.writeEndObject();        

        // only as marker to test
        jsGen.writeStartObject();
        jsGen.writeStringField('Country', 'IL' );
        jsGen.writeStringField('City', 'test city' );
        jsGen.writeEndObject();        
        jsGen.writeEndArray();

        jsGen.writeEndObject();
        jsonData = jsGen.getAsString();
        system.debug('jsonData DATA SENT TO NS !!!!! \n : ' + jsonData);
    }
    SF2NSHandleAccount.handleAccount(idlist, jsonData);
}
```

The account is created on the ERP system, and an it's code is been sent back.

Next, I have an integration class, it's gets the JSON to update, and has a future call (trying to follow SF suggestions, to avoid delays in the work so editing is not held up)

```
public class SF2NSPassJsonData{
    // this class will have a moethod to get the JSON data, from all objects
    // and send it to NS    

    public class ExternalId {
        public String id {get; set;}
        public Integer order_number {get; set;}
    }

    // It gets an integer telling what type of ojbect is handled, so we can set the 
    // NS external ID back into SF.
    // objectType 1 = Account
    // objectType 2 = Contact 
    // objectType 3 = Opprtunity

@future (callout=true) // indicates that this is an asynchronous call
public static void submitData(List<Id> objectIds, String jsonData, Integer objectType) {


        // debugging call, which you can check in console logs
        System.debug(' TEST ALERT ');
        System.debug('jsonData: ' + jsonData);
        String NSaccount = '12345678'; // 
        String NSemail = 'utils@helpdeskemail.com';
        String NSpassword = 'nottellingyoutry123456789';
        String NSrole = '3';  // 3 = Administrator


        // create an HTTPrequest object    

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        // set up the HTTP request with a method, endpoint, header, and body
        req.setMethod('POST');
        // DON'T FORGET TO UPDATE THE FOLLOWING LINE WITH YOUR appid
        req.setEndpoint('https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=114&deploy=1');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'NLAuth nlauth_account=' + NSaccount + ', nlauth_email=' + NSemail + ', nlauth_signature='+NSpassword+', nlauth_role='+NSrole);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
        req.setBody(jsonData);    
        // create a new HTTP object
        Http http = new Http();

        System.debug('Header:' + req.getHeader('Authorization'));
        // create a new HTTP response for receiving the remote response
        // then use it to send the configured HTTPrequest
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        // debugging call, which you can check in console logs
        System.debug('NS replied '+ res.getBody());

        // 3) see above

        // Examine the status code from the HTTPResponse
        // If status code != 200, write debugging information, done
        if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('Error from ' + req.getEndpoint() + ' : ' +
              res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
            return Null;
        }


        // If status code = 200, update each Invoice
        // with the external ID returned by the fulfillment service.
        else {
            system.debug('Return value : res.getBody():' + res.getBody());
            // Retrieve all of the Invoice sObjects
            // originally passed into the method call to prep for update.
            // 
            // 
            // According to Object Type,update with the external data received
            // 
            // 

            if (objectType == 1)
            {
               // First try - Error can't call DML from future method
               Account myAcct = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity FROM Account WHERE Id = :objectIds.get(0) ];
                myAcct.NS_External_ID__c = res.getBody(); 
                try {
                    update myAcct;
                } catch (DmlException e) {
                    // Process exception here
                }



/*                System.debug('objectType = Account');
                List<Account> accounts =
                  [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :objectIds];
                // Create a list of external orders by deserializing the
                // JSON data returned by the fulfillment service.
                System.debug('Account: ' + accounts.size());
                List<ExternalId> orders =
                  (List<ExternalId>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),
                    List<ExternalId>.class);
                // Create a map of Invoice Ids from the retrieved
                // invoices list.
                Map<Id, Account> invoiceMap =
                  new Map<Id, Account>(accounts);
                // Update the Customer numbers in the invoices
                for ( ExternalId order : orders ) {
                  Account acc = invoiceMap.get(order.id);
                  acc.NS_External_ID__c = String.valueOf(order.order_number);
                }
                // Update all objects in the database with a bulk update
                update accounts
               ;
  */          }

         //   also tried to return the id I get to the caller
         // 15:57:26:184 EXCEPTION_THROWN [53]|System.CalloutException: Callout from triggers are currently not supported.
         //   return new List<Id>{'003M000000QnPQu'};
        }      
    }
}
```

- I have tried both a future call - got an error that future calls can't be called from future methods.

[image]

- I tried to return the value to previous class (a middle handler that knows which object to edit) - got error that callout from triggers is not supported.

My question: How do I update the accounts data with value retrieved from a future call?

p.s. - I can get rid of the future call for now, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you'll have to make a static class / variable that will prevent you from running your async process(es) multiple times since you'll get stuck in an infinite loop otherwise. Something like this will accomplish what you are asking for.

Class:

```
SF2NSPassJsonData{
    private static Boolean isAtFutureInUse;
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger trgSF2NSAccount on Account (after update) {
    // if no at future process has been fired off, do process
    if(null == SF2NSHandleAccount.isAtFutureInUse || !SF2NSHandleAccount.isAtFutureInUse){
        // generate JSON String
        ....
        // queue up for webservice call
        SF2NSHandleAccount.isAtFutureInUse = true;
        SF2NSHandleAccount.handleAccount(idlist, jsonData);
    }
}
```

**Your system should in my opinion return to you the Salesforce id if you provide it.** However if you cannot get this information back, Salesforce allows you to use a DML statement called [Upsert](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_upsert.htm)

```
upsert record externalSystemId__c;
```

Truthfully, I would use the streaming API if possible. (even if it's a middle man integration)

- For one, currently, you'll be delaying all updates and they'll have to wait on your response in order for you to process your records in a timely manner. This will delay bulk updates to your system.
- Secondly, your data will be more real time as you won't have to wait on your async process to get queued up and processed.
- Lastly, there is a governor limit on how many @futres you are allowed to run per rolling 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure that this answers my question. This solves the issue of calling a future call while one is already in place. My Q was how to get data returned from the 2nd ERP system. I don't think this answers it.

Comment: Well, as long as you have your external id field set as an external id field you can always upsert it. upsert accountRecord myExtIDField__c;

Answer (score 1):

As I could understand, You are trying to update account from trigger using the value returned from external system.

So it don't looks possible in current approach:

- To callout from trigger @future call is required.
- In future call two operation are done in same thread 1. call-out and 2. Update (same object). It can throw "uncommitted work pending" exception or some other exception as future call updating the same object of which trigger is in execution. @future to @future not supported.

I would like to suggest a schedule class approach which can run hourly or some preferred time and update Accounts by calling out.